# Echo newline with quotes

Tags: bash, echo, newlines

For:

```
$hello="hello
> world"
```

Why does `echo` not print the newline for:

```
echo -e $hello
```

But if I put `$hello` in quotes it does.

```
$ echo "$hello"
hello
world
```

Is this because of ANSI-C Quoting? Shouldn't `echo -e` interpret the newline I inputted?

Comment: It's because of trailing newlines.

Comment: `$hello` without the quotes undergoes shell splitting.

Comment: EngieOP - please search the site for terms like *whitespace* and/or `$IFS` - this is covered exhaustively elsewhere. @DisplayName - this doesn't, in fact, have much to do with *trailing `\n`ewlines* but is rather a result of the shell's default split configuration on its *Internal Field Separator*. And also `echo`'s handling of arguments - it concatenates them on spaces.

Comment: @Nasha - that's not true, exactly. They're not spaces - `echo` does that - they're `\000` NULs. They're separate fields.

Comment: @mikeserv: woops, didn't see your comment, thanks for filling my voids :) .

Answer (score 1):

From the `bash` man page, this describes how word splitting is done according the contents of the `IFS` variable:

> **Word Splitting**
>
> The  shell  scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.
>
> The shell treats each character of `IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters  as  field  terminators.  If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end
>          of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of IFS characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.  If `IFS` has a
>          value  other  than  the  default, then sequences of the whitespace characters space and tab are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the
>          whitespace character is in the value of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character).  Any character in `IFS` that is not `IFS` whitespace, along  with  any  adjacent  `IFS`
>          whitespace  characters,  delimits  a  field.   A sequence of `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.  If the value of `IFS` is null, no word
>          splitting occurs.
>
> Explicit null arguments (`""` or `''`) are retained.  Unquoted implicit null arguments, resulting from the expansion of parameters  that  have  no  values,  are
>          removed.  If a parameter with no value is expanded within double quotes, a null argument results and is retained.
>
> Note that if no expansion occurs, no splitting is performed.

`bash` does word splitting on your variable if it is not double quoted so `hello` and `world` become two different arguments to `echo`. `echo` puts a space between arguments.