# How to get last line of list variable in BusyBox shell script?

Tags: shell-script, busybox

I'm attempting to write a shell script for BusyBox (v1.27.1) wherein the script, in part, needs to extract the last item from a list/multiline variable, which contains a list of absolute file paths.  I've been working on this most of the day, and still no joy.  What am I doing wrong?

```
TARGET_DIRECTORY="/usr/bin"                                          # can be any valid location
ALL_LOG_FILES=$(find $TARGET_DIRECTORY -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*\.log')
LAST_LINE=$($(`echo $ALL_LOG_FILES`) | tail -1)                      # broken here
echo "last line=$LAST_LINE"
```

Comment: Likely the issue is that the unquoted expansion `$ALL_LOG_FILES` is subject to word splitting, so there is no "last line" - see related [Echo newline with quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176660/echo-newline-with-quotes)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, but how does this apply to my situation?  The file paths in my variable have no spaces, only line ends (presumably).

Comment: It should become clear if you compare the output of `echo $ALL_LOG_FILES` vs `echo "$ALL_LOG_FILES"`. BTW you seem to have more layers of command substitution than you need there - `LAST_LINE=$(echo "$ALL_LOG_FILES" | tail -1)` should be sufficient.

Comment: @steeldriver That appears to have been the problem.  If you post your answer, I'll accept.